# UTF-8 format output with Unicode \uxxxx

Tags: c, unicode, utf-8, arduino, output

I am stuck at this point at writing to a file with strings of [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) format. I now have the value of 4E25 (for example). But I need to write to a text file with prefix \u. Since I can not directly append a `\u` to `4E25`, what can I do to ouput the "\u4e25" in [C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_%28programming_language%29)?

Comment: [WAT?](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat)

Comment: Hi, I believe I put this question pretty vague. let's say I have \u0024 which represents "$" as character. I am trying to write to a file with this "$" so that I need to write\u0024 to the file. The problem is I am able to get this 0024 but I can not directly append \u to 0024 so that I would be able to output the character to the file. Do you know a way I can handle this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @userXXX Why "can't you directly append `\u`"? What do you mean by that?

Comment: since is I think \ is the escape character. if I append \u to 0024 i would actually need to write a \\u0024, but then it is not what I want

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that you simply want to print the text string `"\u4e25"` to file, but you can't because the compiler is interpreting the escape sequence and printing the actual unicode character instead?  If so, the answer is simple:  the escape code for the `'\'` character is `\\`.  So you would `fprintf` `"\\u4e25"` in your source code to generate `"\u4e25"` in the file.

Answer (score 0):

The `\u` is interpreted as part of a value. i.e. `\u00aa` in your code isn't interpreted as an escape character followed by the characters `0024`. The compiler will just convert all of that sequence to the correct bytes (in this case `0xc2a3` in UTF-8).

There's nothing to stop you using `printf("\u00aa");`, but you can't do, `printf("\u%s", str);` for example. If you need to get the UTF-8 codes in directly, you could use the octal, e.g.

`printf("\302\243 \n"); // print UTF-8 sequence directly`